# Why is that only one element triggers the action even though I used .each?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this to take the value of an `input` and put it into another one at the end of the page:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.free-lesson input[type="text"]').each(function () {
    jQuery(".free-lesson input[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var freeLessonContent = jQuery(this).val();
      jQuery("#mce-EMAIL").val(freeLessonContent);
    });
  });
});
```

there are many `.free-lesson` divs but strangely only the last one works (the others don't put any value to the `input` in the form.

How to fix this?

This is the site: http://www.chineselearnonline.com/amember/signup40.php

Comment: Why do you need here `.each`? If you want it to be related to `jQuery(this).val();` then you are doing it slightly wrong. `this` in that scope is not related to `this` of `.each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add the `foreach` in there. The `this` you reference in the `foreach` is not th element you need. Try this out.

```
jQuery('.free-lesson-form [type="submit"]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery('#mce-EMAIL').val(jQuery(this).prev().val()); //find the element previous to the one that was clicked. 
  //You may also want to use .parent() and find the input as this is more reliable if you move the markup around
});
```

What I've done here is to bind to the click event of all submits inside the `free-lesson-form` div. And then capture the value of the text input that is next to the button that was clicked. Tried this out on your site and it works for the current markup.